# Accepting only numbers as input in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to accept only numbers in Python, say like using `raw_input()`?

I know I can always get the input and catch a `ValueError` exception, but I was interested in knowing whether there was someway I could force the prompt to accept only numbers and freeze on any other input.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I am making a small script that accepts marks as input.

Comment: You could probably write your own class that does that, I don't think there's any such built-in feature.

Comment: @Alfred: I've done the same thing, writing a grading script. Just raise a `ValueError` on non-numeric input.

Comment: @David: Aah! I thought there had to be a way in Python.

Comment: @Alfred: Well, evidently there is, although I figured it would be way more trouble than it's worth - unless you have code to copy and paste, that is ;-) (or are familiar with what the `termios` and `fcntl` modules can do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/faq/library.html#how-do-i-get-a-single-keypress-at-a-time):

> **How do I get a single keypress at a time?**
>
> For Unix variants: There are several
>   solutions. It’s straightforward to do
>   this using curses, but curses is a
>   fairly large module to learn. Here’s a
>   solution without curses:

```
import termios, fcntl, sys, os
fd = sys.stdin.fileno()

oldterm = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
newattr[3] = newattr[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newattr)

oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)

try:
    while 1:
        try:
            c = sys.stdin.read(1)
            print "Got character", `c`
        except IOError: pass
finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldterm)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
```

> You need the termios and the fcntl
>   module for any of this to work, and
>   I’ve only tried it on Linux, though it
>   should work elsewhere. In this code,
>   characters are read and printed one at
>   a time.
>
> termios.tcsetattr() turns off stdin’s
>   echoing and disables canonical mode.
>   fcntl.fnctl() is used to obtain
>   stdin’s file descriptor flags and
>   modify them for non-blocking mode.
>   Since reading stdin when it is empty
>   results in an IOError, this error is
>   caught and ignored.

Using this, you could grab the character, check if it's a number, and then display it. I haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: Clearly we were thinking along the same lines ;-) +1 for the code, though. I just tried that out and with a few minor changes, it seems to work exactly as desired for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no. I've never heard of such a thing being possible with a terminal, in Python or any other language.

The closest way I can think of to fake it would be to put the terminal in silent mode (so that input characters are not echoed) and unbuffered mode (so that you get each character typed as it's typed, without waiting for the end of the line), then read each input character one by one; if it's a digit, print it and append it to a string, otherwise discard it. But I'm not even sure if the terminal would allow you to do that.