# Python user must only enter float numbers

Tags: python, input, numbers

I am trying to find out how to make it so the user [only enters numbers <0] and [no letters] allowed. Can someone show me how I would set this up. I have tried to set up try/catch blocks but I keep getting errors.

```
edgeone = input("Enter the first edge of the triangle: ")
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I suggest using the [python regular expressions module](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: I am new to python with only like 2 weeks experience. I just don't understand the correct way to go about setting this try/catch up or maybe I should use and if/else. That's why I asked for help because I would visually like to see the way someone sets this up.

Answer (score 0):

you must use except handler for this case :

```
try:
    value = int(raw_input("Enter your number:"))
    if not ( value < 0 ):
        raise ValueError()
except ValueError:
    print "you must enter a number <0 "
else:
    print value #or something else
```

Also This question already has an answer here: [Accepting only numbers as input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144529/accepting-only-numbers-as-input-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want numbers only > 0, or do you want less than zero? Anyway to do this you can using try/except, inside a while loop.

**For Python 3, which I think you are using?**

```
goodnumber = False
while not goodnumber:
    try:
        edgeone = int(input('Enter the first edge of the triangle:'))
        if edgeone > 0:
            print('thats a good number, thanks')
            goodnumber = True
        else:
            print('thats not a number greater than 0, try again please')
    except ValueError:
        print('Thats not a number, try again please')
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
i = 1
while(type(i)!=float):
    i=input("enter no.")
    try:
        int(i):
    except:
        try:
            i = float(i)
        except:
            pass
print(i)
```

Comment: It would be nice to add some explanation with the code.