# Writing a normal python code into function called computepay()

Tags: python, function

How can I write the following program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour using input to compute gross pay in a function called computepay() and use the function to do the computation. I want the function to return a value. In short, I want function to do it for me so that I can reduce the manual work from my side. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
sh = input("Enter hours:")
try:
    fh = float(sh)
except:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input")
    quit() # Commenting this line out will yield different result
sr = input("Enter Rate:")
try:
    fr = float(sr)
except:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input")
    quit() # Commenting this line out will yield different result

if fh > 40:
    reg = fr  * fh
    otp = (fh - 40.0) * (fr * 0.5)
    xp = reg + otp
else:
    xp = fh * fr
print("Pay:",xp)
```

Comment: Your code works for me ok. However, I expect you don't really want to `quit()` if a non number is entered. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53635119/13253198) for help on only accepting numbers.

Comment: @gnodab
Can you take my code and put it all inside a function and share it?

Answer (score 0):

tell me if this is what you are looking for:

```
def computepay(sh, sr):
    """
    compute pay

    :param sh: float, hours
    :param sr: float, rate
    :return:
    """

    # reference object change
    fh = sh
    fr = sr

    if fh > 40:
        reg = fr * fh
        otp = (fh - 40.0) * (fr * 0.5)
        xp = reg + otp
    else:
        xp = fh * fr

    print("Pay:", xp)
    return xp
```

Comment: Did you run this code and is it running fine on your side? Kindly tell me. Because it's not working on my side.

Comment: yes, you only have to run as follows: computepay(sh=2, sr=3)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will accept only numbers as input. Also, this demonstrates using a function for your calculations:

```
sh = 'none'

while(type(sh)!=float):
    sh=input("Enter hours:")
    try:
        sh=float(sh)
    except:
        pass

sr = 'none'
while(type(sr)!=float):
    sr=input("Enter Rate:")
    try:
        sr=float(sr)
    except:
        pass

def calculate_pay(hours, rate):
  if hours > 40:
    reg = rate  * hours
    otp = (hours - 40.0) * (rate * 0.5)
    xp = reg + otp
  else:
    xp = hours * rate
  return xp

print("Pay:",calculate_pay(sh, sr))
```

---

#### Edit

Please search and look into how to create functions in Python. It is really quite simple. In your case, if you want everything in a function, then do this:

```
def get_paycheck():
  sh = 'none'

  while(type(sh)!=float):
      sh=input("Enter hours:")
      try:
          sh=float(sh)
      except:
          pass

  sr = 'none'
  while(type(sr)!=float):
      sr=input("Enter Rate:")
      try:
          sr=float(sr)
      except:
          pass

  if sh > 40:
    reg = sr  * sh
    otp = (sh - 40.0) * (sr * 0.5)
    xp = reg + otp
  else:
    xp = sh * sr
  return xp
```

Now you can call the function from anywhere like so:

```
print("Pay:",get_paycheck())
```

Comment: How can you write complete code in a function like every line of code in def function (not any line of code outside of it)?

Comment: @FionaDaniel Sure. Just wrap all of your code with the def function with no input parameters. You're already getting your input within the function. But somewhere, something has to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine.
`quit() # Commenting this line out will yield different result`
Yes, if you don't exit, the program continues how ever it can.

I modified my answer to incorporate your request in the comments. Here I use a recursive to retry getting the argument if float() fails:

```
def compute_pay(hours, rate) :
        """ Comute pay for given hours and rate per hour """
        if hours > 40:
                reg = rate  * hours
                otp = (hours - 40.0) * (rate * 0.5)
                return reg + otp
        else:
                return hours * rate

def get_argument(arg_name):
    """ Recursively tries to get arguments """
    try:
        # attempt to float the input
        return float(input(f"Enter {arg_name}:"))
    except ValueError:
        # retry if failed 
        print("Error, please enter numeric input...")
        return get_argument(arg_name)

# your program is launched here: python3 this_program.py
if __name__=="__main__":
        # get the arguments, retrying recursively
        hours_worked, hourly_rate = get_argument('hours'), get_argument('rate')

        # compute the pay 
        pay = compute_pay(hours_worked, hourly_rate)

        # output 
        print(f"Pay: {pay}")

        # exit gracefully: 0 means "all good"
        exit(0)
```